# how do i get the pod in running status?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

sakshi_jain@192 ~ %  kubectl get po -n dev-923   
NAME                                            READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
my-pod-d5b854d94-ndgtd   0/1     Error    1          5m40s

````
Events:

  Type     Reason     Age                   From     Message

  ----     ------     ----                  ----     -------

  Warning  Unhealthy  56m (x2 over 78m)     kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.251.64.173:8444/actuator/health/probe": dial tcp 10.251.64.173:8444: connect: connection refused

  Warning  BackOff    6m9s (x203 over 84m)  **kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container

  Warning  Unhealthy  0s (x16 over 88m)     kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.251.64.173:8444/actuator/health/probe": dial tcp 10.251.64.173:8444: connect: connection refused
```**



how can i get one pod in ready status ? I have tried checking logs , scaling cluster 



NAME                                            READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
my-pod-d5b854d94-ndgtd   1/1     Error    1          5m40s
````

Comment: Some context as to what you are trying to run would be helpful. In general, your pods would not be in the `ready` state unless it satisfies the condition of the readiness probe check

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you need to clarify what are you trying to do in the pod. is the web server running?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error it is clear that the web server inside the pod is not running. hence the liveness and readyness probes are failing.

It appears like the pod is throwing java exception and is java process is getting terminated. Ensure that the java process get started and the web server comes online without issues.

Comment: Normal Pulling 16m (x38 over 4h31m) kubelet Pulling image “6ECR repo Name”
Warning Unhealthy 6m12s (x5 over 4h14m) kubelet Readiness probe failed: Get “http://10.252.66.111:8444/actuator/health/probe”: dial tcp 10.252.66.111:8444: connect: connection refused
Warning BackOff 94s (x824 over 4h26m) kubelet Back-off restarting failed container



at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.11.RELEASE]
… 22 more

Comment: Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling    16m (x38 over 4h31m)   kubelet  Pulling image "ECR repo name"
  Warning  Unhealthy  6m12s (x5 over 4h14m)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.252.66.111:8444/actuator/health/probe": dial tcp 10.252.66.111:8444: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff    94s (x824 over 4h26m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container